# how to hide the top `xAxis lables` of mpandroidchart line chart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I use mpandroidchart, I set the `xAxis` position as bothside ,and set the lable, the code :

```
xAxis.setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);
xAxis.setDrawLabels(true);
```

but I want only show the bottom `xAxis` lables and hide the top `xAxis` lables. how can I do for what I want?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check my answer, and accept if it is useful.

Comment: it isn't useful , I post screenshot , I want show the `bottom` and hide the `top`

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Comment: I know that , but I want set the `XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED` and hide the top lables , have others way ?

Comment: I can not understand your requirement. If you want to hide the top xValues, then why you are not using `XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM` code?

Comment: Because if I set the `XAxisPosition.BOTTOM` the top gridline horizontal change dashed , I want the solid line , I don't know how to do , so I think that set the `XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED` and then hide the lables.

Comment: Can you please add screenshot with that problem (Grid line horizontal change dashed) ?

Comment: I have posted the screenshot , I want the top line as a solid line

Comment: Check my edited answer and let me know. I am not sure about this, but might be helpful.

Comment: it doesn't work , thanks for your time , but I can't check the answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I suggest you to ask to Philipp Jahoda in his library. He will surely help you.

Comment: Thanks , I will do .

Comment: Have you got any solution? Please share if you got any solution.

Comment: Sorry, latest I'm very busy , I add a `Limitline` on the top to cover the dashed, and resolve my problem , but it is not the best way I think

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
dataSet.setDrawValues(false);
```

Check this [link](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ChartData-class) for more details.

> **Edit 1:**

Replace

```
xAxis.setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);
```

With

```
xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
```

> **Edit 2:**

Try to add:

```
xAxis.disableGridDashedLine();
```